# ...be very loved!

Tags: adjectives, passive-voice

I am just wondering why the following construction would not be acceptable for a lot of speakers of the English language:

> Fiona ***was*** ***very loved*** among her classmates.

Also, I am wondering if the bold words are a part of a passive structure or an adjectival phrase.

Comment: But it *would* be acceptable for a lot of English speakers . . .

Comment: @Jason: What do you mean by your remark? Do you think that this construction is very common among native speakers?

Comment: I didn't say it was very common. I said it was acceptable. It's grammatical, and most people would not mark it as incorrect. I'd say that *Fiona was very loved* ***by*** *her classmates* would be more common—but that means something different.

Answer (score 1):

According to the structure of the sentence, 'loved' is an adjective here because:

1. It is pre-modified by 'very'.
2. In case it was a Passive participle it would be post-modified by 'very much'.

For example:
'She is loved by everybody very much.'
'She is very nice / sympathetic, etc.